# Android: ComponentInfo: java null pointer exception after returning to App

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

My app works without any problem until close my app and return after more than 15 min aprox it crash, if I return to my App after only 5 min all seems right. I can't find the problem please help!!!

LogCat

```
    02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.raigo.itivamin/com.raigo.itivamin.Bartabs}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.raigo.itivamin/com.raigo.itivamin.ObjetivosActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:210)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.raigo.itivamin/com.raigo.itivamin.ObjetivosActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1808)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:737)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:401)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:240)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at com.raigo.itivamin.Bartabs.addTab(Bartabs.java:65)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at com.raigo.itivamin.Bartabs.setTabs(Bartabs.java:37)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at com.raigo.itivamin.Bartabs.onCreate(Bartabs.java:29)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     ... 11 more
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at com.raigo.itivamin.ObjetivosActivity.onCreate(ObjetivosActivity.java:25)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
02-06 20:39:43.534: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     ... 23 more
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.raigo.itivamin"
    android:versionCode="10"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application  android:name="com.raigo.itivamin.iTIVAapp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/app_theme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".IngresodatosActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                    <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="Bartabs" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ObjetivosActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"></activity>  
        <activity android:name=".BombaActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".OpioideActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>    
        <activity android:name=".HipnoticoActivity"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>   
        <activity android:name="org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity" />   
        <activity android:name=".GraficaActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".SimuladorActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".AyudaActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"></activity>

        <service android:name=".SomeService1"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Bartabs.java

```
package com.raigo.itivamin;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * @author Adil Soomro
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class Bartabs extends TabActivity  {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
//boolean simulador =false;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        //simulador= extras.getBoolean("simulador");
        setTabs() ;

    }

    private void setTabs()
    {

    if (((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).simulador==false){         
        addTab(getString(R.string.target), R.drawable.tab_objetivos, ObjetivosActivity.class);
        addTab(getString(R.string.pump), R.drawable.tab_bomba, BombaActivity.class);
        addTab2(getString(R.string.pk_pd), R.drawable.tab_chart,GraficaActivity.class);
        addTab(getString(R.string.help), R.drawable.tab_help, AyudaActivity.class);
    } else{
        addTab(getString(R.string.scheme), R.drawable.tab_bomba, SimuladorActivity.class);
        addTab2(getString(R.string.pk_pd), R.drawable.tab_chart,GraficaActivity.class);
        addTab(getString(R.string.help), R.drawable.tab_help, AyudaActivity.class);
    }

    }

    private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c)
    {
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId); 

        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
        TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);

        title.setText(labelId);
                ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        spec.setContent(intent);

        tabHost.addTab(spec);
        //tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

    }

    private void addTab2(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c)
    {
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, c).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId); 

        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
        TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);

        title.setText(labelId);
                ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        spec.setContent(intent);

        tabHost.addTab(spec);
        //tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    }


    //@Override
    //public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

    //  if (tabId.equals("tabPK/PD")==true && (((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).cambio==true)){ 
    //    LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
    //    manager.destroyActivity("tabPK/PD", true);
    //   manager.startActivity("tabPK/PD", new Intent(this, GraficaActivity.class));
    //  }
    //}


}
```

ObjetivosActivity.java

```
package com.raigo.itivamin;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ObjetivosActivity extends Activity implements OnValueChangeListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        if (((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).modelo2.equals("halogenado")==false){
        setContentView(R.layout.objetivospage_sep);
        }
        else    
        {
        setContentView(R.layout.objetivospage_bal);
        }                   

        //valores por defecto
        ((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).Tinduccion=5;     
        ((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).tcx=180;
        ((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).objetivo="efecto";
        //((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).deltainfusion=15;
        ((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).cambio=true;

        final Button btn_opt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_optimizar);

        if (((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).mezclado==true){
             btn_opt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else if (((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).modelo2.equals("halogenado")==false) {
             btn_opt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        /////////
        final Button btn_ind = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_induccion);
         btn_ind.setText((int)((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).Tinduccion+" "+getString(R.string._min));
        //se crean los objetivos del farmaco 1

         final NumberPicker np_ini1 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker_ini1);
         final NumberPicker np_man1 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker_man1);
         final NumberPicker np_sal1 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker_sal1);

        String[] nums = new String[120];

        for(int i=1; i<nums.length+1; i++)
           nums[i-1] = Double.toString(i/10.0);

        np_ini1.setMaxValue(nums.length-1);
        np_ini1.setMinValue(0);
        np_ini1.setDisplayedValues(nums);
        np_ini1.setValue((int) (((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).ini1*10-1));
        np_ini1.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        np_ini1.setOnValueChangedListener(this);

        np_man1.setMaxValue(nums.length-1);
        np_man1.setMinValue(0);
        np_man1.setDisplayedValues(nums);
        np_man1.setValue((int) (((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).man1*10-1));
        np_man1.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        np_man1.setOnValueChangedListener(this);

        np_sal1.setMaxValue(nums.length-1);
        np_sal1.setMinValue(0);
        np_sal1.setDisplayedValues(nums);
        np_sal1.setValue((int) (((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).sal1*10-1));
        np_sal1.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        np_sal1.setOnValueChangedListener(this);

        if (((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).modelo2.equals("schnider") && ((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).mezclado==false){
        //se crean los objetivos del farmaco 2

            final NumberPicker np_ini2 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker_ini2);
            final NumberPicker np_man2 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker_man2);
            final NumberPicker np_sal2 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker_sal2);

        String[] nums2 = new String[80];

        for(int i=1; i<nums2.length+1; i++)
           nums2[i-1] = Double.toString(i/10.0);

        np_ini2.setMaxValue(nums2.length-1);
        np_ini2.setMinValue(0);
        np_ini2.setDisplayedValues(nums2);
        np_ini2.setValue((int) (((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).ini2*10-1));
        np_ini2.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        np_ini2.setOnValueChangedListener(this);

        np_man2.setMaxValue(nums2.length-1);
        np_man2.setMinValue(0);
        np_man2.setDisplayedValues(nums2);
        np_man2.setValue((int) (((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).man2*10-1));
        np_man2.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        np_man2.setOnValueChangedListener(this);

        np_sal2.setMaxValue(nums2.length-1);
        np_sal2.setMinValue(0);
        np_sal2.setDisplayedValues(nums2);
        np_sal2.setValue((int) (((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).sal2*10-1));
        np_sal2.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        np_sal2.setOnValueChangedListener(this);
        }
        else if (((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).mezclado==true){
             //se crean los objetivos del farmaco 2

            final NumberPicker np_ini2 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker_ini2);
            final NumberPicker np_man2 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker_man2);
            final NumberPicker np_sal2 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker_sal2);

            String[] nums2 = new String[81];

            for(int i=1; i<nums2.length; i++)
               nums2[i-1] = Double.toString(i/10.0);

            nums2[80] = "-";

            np_ini2.setMaxValue(nums2.length-1);
            np_ini2.setMinValue(0);
            np_ini2.setDisplayedValues(nums2);
            np_ini2.setValue(80);
            np_ini2.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
            np_ini2.setOnValueChangedListener(this);

            np_man2.setMaxValue(nums2.length-1);
            np_man2.setMinValue(0);
            np_man2.setDisplayedValues(nums2);
            np_man2.setValue(80);
            np_man2.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
            np_man2.setOnValueChangedListener(this);

            np_sal2.setMaxValue(nums2.length-1);
            np_sal2.setMinValue(0);
            np_sal2.setDisplayedValues(nums2);
            np_sal2.setValue(80);
            np_sal2.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
            np_sal2.setOnValueChangedListener(this);    
        }
        else if (((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).modelo2.equals("halogenado")){
            NumberPicker np_mac = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker_mac);
            String[] nums2 = new String[30];

            for(int i=1; i<nums2.length+1; i++)
               nums2[i-1] = Double.toString(i/10.0);

            np_mac.setMaxValue(nums2.length-1);
            np_mac.setMinValue(0);
            np_mac.setDisplayedValues(nums2);
            np_mac.setValue(0);
            np_mac.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
            np_mac.setOnValueChangedListener(this);
        }


    }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            NumberPicker np_ini1 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker_ini1);
            NumberPicker np_man1 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker_man1);
            NumberPicker np_sal1 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker_sal1);


            np_ini1.setValue((int) (((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).ini1*10-1));
            np_man1.setValue((int) (((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).man1*10-1));
            np_sal1.setValue((int) (((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).sal1*10-1));


            if (((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).modelo2.equals("halogenado")==false){
                NumberPicker np_ini2 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker_ini2);
                NumberPicker np_man2 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker_man2);
                NumberPicker np_sal2 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker_sal2);

                np_ini2.setValue((int) (((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).ini2*10-1));
                np_man2.setValue((int) (((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).man2*10-1));
                np_sal2.setValue((int) (((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).sal2*10-1));

                if (((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).mezclado==true){

                    if (((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).ini2==0 && ((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).man2==0){
                        np_ini2.setValue(80);
                        np_man2.setValue(80);   
                    } else {
                    np_ini2.setValue((int) (((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).ini2*10-1));
                    np_man2.setValue((int) (((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).man2*10-1));
                    }

                    np_sal2.setValue(80);
                }

            }

    }

.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at com.raigo.itivamin.ObjetivosActivity.onCreate(ObjetivosActivity.java:25)
```

The error seems to point to this line:

```
if (((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).modelo2.equals("halogenado")==false){
```

So either `(iTIVAapp)getApplication()` is null or `.modelo2` is null. You can test which value is null with your debugger or via LogCat statements.

If `modelo2` may or may not be null you can write your condition backwards:

```
if(!"halogenado".equals(((iTIVAapp)getApplication()).modelo2)){ 
    // "!" means "!= true" which must mean "false" for a boolean
```

Comment: What is causing to the application iTIVAapp class to reset after sometime?, because if I return to my app after 5 min all is right, I need conserva the data in the Application Class so when my aplication goes to background, when the User return the App all the values in the variables in the iTIVA application class can be returned. (excuse my english is not my naive language)

Comment: You need to save the important data. I recommend using SharedPreferences to save this information in a permanent location, please read [`Data Storage`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for examples and other methods.